# How to globally customize error messages vee-validate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following configuration using “extend” in vee-validate to customize messages, this is working locally for me, now I need to take it to a global one.

[Import vee-validate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YmjB.png)

[Global scope vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suttP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may import [`localize`](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/localization.html#lazily-importing-locales) and lazy load your locales.

We do have custom rules, so we added translations from `vue-i18n` on top of it. As showcased in the [Using other i18n libraries](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/localization.html#using-other-i18n-libraries) section.